# NSBundle argument in a method call

Tags: objective-c, path, nsbundle

I have to call this method:

```
[super initWithPNGFileName: "/Volumes/SAGITTER/Lavoro/Progetti xCode/IVBricker test/ball.png" andGame:game andCGRect:CGRectMake(x,y,16,16)];
```

So when I put this on the iPhone, the path is not right. I know I must use NSBundle but if I do

```
[super initWithPNGFileName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ball" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"/"] andGame:game andCGRect:CGRectMake(x,y,16,16)];
```

I get the alert: "passing argument 1 of 'initWithPNGFileName:andGame:andCGRect:' from incompatible pointer type"

How should I proceed using NSBundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `[super initWithPNGFileName: "/Volum...` is 100% correct code I think this message expects a C-Style string.
But `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:...]` will return a NSString object.

Try to pass `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ball" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"/"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st call passes c-string to `initWithPNGFileName:` method, while `-pathForResource:` returns NSString. Get c-string from the path you get from bundle and pass that string to your method:

```
[super initWithPNGFileName:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ball" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"/"] UTF8String]
                   andGame:game 
                 andCGRect:CGRectMake(x,y,16,16)];
```